Definition of semisimple algebra over a field
Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $k$ (may be infinite dimensional). There are different (but equivalent) definitions for $A$ to be semisimple algebra.
In some books and notes, it is defined as:

$A$ is semisimple if all non-zero modules over $A$ are semisimple, i.e. all non-zero modules over $A$ are sum of simple submodules.

Q.1 Excluding zero module in this definition is necessary? I thought that $0$ is direct sum of empty family of simple modules; so it is semisimple module. Am I doing any mistake here?

Q.2 Historically, who first defined the concept of semisimple algebra? Was it first defined for only finite dimensional algebra? (I am considering infinite dimensional algebras also.)

For Q1 you are absolutely right. The empty direct sum is the zero module. (More generally, the empty colimit in any category is the same as an initial object.)
Related:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities
For Q2 it seems that Cartan, Frobenius, Molien and Wedderburn were the first ones to study semi-simple algebras.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemisimpleAlgebra.html
